# Build make file arm microcontroller

Tags: c, makefile, build, obd-ii, stm32f1

We bought an ECU emulator made with stm32f103,
The source files are attached to them. But there is no file (BIN or HEX) and there is a make file that needs to be built, but when I tried to create it but it is not possible for me,
If you have experience with this process, thank you for guiding me ...

[image: Files]

Best Regard.

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile
After you installed the necessary compiler (maybe GCC), you should navigate in  command line to the target folder and use probably the 'make' command. You should share the makefile to see clearly.

Comment: Might be less work to simply add the files to your favourite IDE, one by one until you get it to build. Manually enter the compiler options.